# IF Statement being ignored when reading/writing from external txt.file

Tags: python

Beginner Programmer here, I am trying to make a program that would act as a way to register and check to see if the username imputed was already taken. My code doesn't produce any errors but the IF statement is always ignored and never produces the error message if a Username is taken.

```
username = input("Username: ")
def register():
    with open("Usernames.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.write("\n")
        for line in f:
            if line == username :
                print("Error")
            else:
                f.write(username)

register()
```

Comment: What output do you see when you `print(line, username)`

Answer (score 2):

`input` strips the newline from input it reads; a file iterator does not.

```
username = input("Username: ")
def register():
    with open("Usernames.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.write("\n")
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if line == username :
                print("Error")
            else:
                f.write(username)
```

Comment: I thnk you want to add a break when the user is found and dedent that `else` so that username is only written when the user is not found.

Comment: The break dedent from else fixed the problem of the Username still being added, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Mixing reading and writing will never work here, if the last item in your list is the existing username then you'd have rewritten it `n` times before finding out it already exists.

Instead you should just read the names into a list and then just check with `in`

```
if username in username_list:
    print("Error")
else:
    write_to_file(username)
    username_list.append(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `f` object in python corresponds to your file. For reading the lines from it you can use the `.read().splitlines()` methods, just like below:

```
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    if line == username :
        print("Error")
    else:
        f.write(username)
```

Comment: `readlines` doesn't strip the newline character so OP will continue to have the same problem. Generally, one avoids reading an entire file when the goal is simply to iterate lines. It makes little difference for small files but needlessly uses extra resources.

Comment: Great, I'll correct my answer. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
username = input("Username: ")


def register():
    with open("Usernames.txt", "r+") as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():  # We must read the file first and then split it into lines
            # Also for debug I advise you to look at the state of the program, for example like this
            # print(line)
            if line.strip() == username:  # strip to ignore spaces and other "empty" characters
                print("Error")
                return  # Stop if error
        f.write('\n'+username)


register()
```

I would be glad if I helped)
Tell me if something is not clear.